# CodeIgniter ajax upload image (ajax works, not CodeIgniter)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I do know how to upload an image by ajax in a traditional way. However, with the `library upload` from CodeIgniter I can't figure it out.

But first, let me just tell you that **I do not use a form** at all.

```
if(!empty($_FILES)){

    $this->load->helper('global_helper');

    $config['upload_path']   = base_url() + "public/images/";
    $config['file_name']     = randomName();
    $config['allowed_types'] = "jpg|png|bmp";
    $config['max_size']   = '500';
    $config['overwrite']      = FALSE;

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if(!$this->upload->do_upload()){
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        print_r($error);
    }
}
```

This does not work because I'm receiving the following error:

```
Array
(
    [error] => <p>You did not select a file to upload.</p>
)
```

But I actually did and it was actually uploaded to the server, because if I print out the `$_FILES` I receive:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => no_image.png
            [type] => image/png
            [tmp_name] => C:\xampp\tmp\php1715.tmp
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 6361
        )

)
```

Might be the problem of the input being in an Array(of Array[0])?

The javascript code is the following:

```
event.stopPropagation();
event.preventDefault();
var data = new FormData();

if(picture != undefined){ 
    $.each(picture, function (key, value) {
        data.append(key, value);
    });
}

$.ajax({
    url: 'ajax_add',
    type: 'POST',
    data: data,
    cache: false,
    processData: false,  
    contentType: false, 
    success: function(aux){
        console.log(aux);
    }
});
```

I do not want to use the traditional way, but if I have too..

Thanks.

Comment: what is the name of the form field on the HTML side? || <input type="file" name="??" /> || also are you using form multipart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if it can work, because the file uploading class is designed to be used with a form, but you can try this

```
$this->upload->do_upload(0);
```

If it does what I think, it will select the first item of the `$_FILES` array. By default, it tries to find `$_FILES['userfile']`, who doesn't exists here (which is why you have the error).

Give it a try, and we'll see if it works :)

Comment: I was so close. I tried before `$this->upload->do_upload($_FILES[0]);`, without any success. But your solution worked. Thank you.

Comment: You can understand why it works by looking directly in the `do_upload()` function located in `system/library/Upload.php` :)

Comment: Yes, `$field = 'userfile'`.

Comment: @Linesofcode we'll i'm stuck in even traditional upload, actually it works my function is doing the upload and db insertion thing but when i throw data to db it doesn't come back to show the image. would you like to see the code to help it ? Thanks